# Android / Xamarin, Open file with intent and close app after back button pressed

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent

I have a problem with a feature of my application.
I need to open external files to display them like .jpeg or .xls for example. For that I use Intents to open them with the default system application and it works fine.
But in a case where we will first open a document, for example a photo. this will display in the default app and then I go back and forth in my app. Everything is OK
But then I'm going to open another standard .xls document, it'll open the document in the appropriate application and going back will show the opened image first and not my application again.
I don't understand why it happens like this.
What I would like is that when we do previous in a file viewer app, the app quits and doesn't stay in the ActivityManager.
Is it possible ?
I have already tried some intent flags but without success.

My code here :

```cs
                        Android.Net.Uri fileUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Android.App.Application.Context, "com.app.fileprovider"
                     , file);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
                        intent.SetData(fileUri);
                        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
                        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory);
                        Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
                        return true;
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Max B

Comment: Try removing the NoHistory tag when you create the new intent.

Comment: Hey ! Yeah I' have already remove this flag, It was just a test but does'nt work.

Comment: I think you could not do it,when you open the other app to display your files,the apps will be add into a stack unless you close it manually.You could iterate through your application process and close applications other than your own with `ActivityManager`,but this will close some apps that you don't want to close.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks Leo, I'll try with the ActivityManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO !
My bad, It was not a real problem.
It was a design error.
Indeed during my call of my function to call the intention I linked my opening event without then unbinding it. So that with each call I recalled X times my file opening function without ever destroying my variable or my variable instance.

The Intent Works Well
Thanks for the comments